# chrome is not supporting svg file

Tags: xml, svg

whenever i am trying to run my svg file, it is showing the message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." The code is here

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>My first SVG</h1>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" 
    fill="yellow"/></svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You saved this markup as a `.svg` file ? This is html, not svg. Even if your html does contain an svg node, it's still html. So either add an `.html` extension to your file, either remove all html elements from the markup (keep only what is between `<svg>` and `</svg>`. Ps: you'll also probably need to add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in your svg opening tag if you want to make it a standalone file

Comment: thank you, now it is working